# SQL query to update a record based on the max value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

### The Problem

I have this table. (You can also view it in [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=71bdb08e59aa79f02c8ff5fa71fcb6ca).)

| Id | Version | Item No. | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 31 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 31 | tasty |
| 3 | 2 | 31 | kinda tasty |
| 4 | NULL | 32 |  |
| 5 | 1 | 32 | meh |
| 6 | 2 | 32 | alright |
| 7 | 3 | 32 | fabulous |
| 8 | NULL | 33 | ambivalent |
| 9 | 1 | 33 | gross |
| 10 | 2 | 33 | puke |

The 1st column is the primary key.
The 2nd and 3rd column are integers.
The 4th column is a VARCHAR.

For every unique **Item No.** where its **Version** is NULL, I want to look at the record with the highest **Version** value, take the content of its **Notes** field, and copy it over.

This is much easier to understand visually; after the command is run, the table should look like this:

| Id | Version | Item No. | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 31 | ***kinda tasty*** |
| 2 | 1 | 31 | tasty |
| 3 | 2 | 31 | kinda tasty |
| 4 | NULL | 32 | ***fabulous*** |
| 5 | 1 | 32 | meh |
| 6 | 2 | 32 | alright |
| 7 | 3 | 32 | fabulous |
| 8 | NULL | 33 | ambivalent |
| 9 | 1 | 33 | gross |
| 10 | 2 | 33 | puke |

### Explanation of the Changes

- for Item No. 31, "kinda tasty" was copied over because it's in the record with the highest Version number, and the target cell is not occupied.
- for Item No. 32, "fabulous" was copied over for the same reason.
- "puke" was NOT copied over to replace "ambivalent", because the target cell is occupied.

### The Question

What is the query to achieve this in SQL Server?

I know that I need a way of grouping records together by **Item No.**, find the one with the highest **Version** value, take its **Notes** value, and copy it to the record where the **Version** is NULL, but I am having trouble translating this to SQL.

Comment: Please do not add Images to display sample data and expected outcome, always provide these in text format so we can copy paste the sample data into our test environment in stead of having to type over all your sample data from the image

Comment: Images replaced with copy-pastable tables

Comment: Please let me know if there's some SQL playground website where I can setup the tables for people to play around with.

Comment: you can use https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: @AaronBertrand It will be a one-off change that I have to do on a production table. The table here is simplified and anonymized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t SET notes = (
   SELECT TOP 1 s.notes 
   FROM t s 
   WHERE s.item_no = t.item_no 
   ORDER BY version DESC
) WHERE version IS NULL AND notes IS NULL
```

Check [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba5f2467665a9f070446f1e73a4e3451)

Comment: Thanks, seems to work perfectly! I like the use of `TOP 1` as a way of getting the maximum value in the Version column.

Answer (score 6):

Use an updatable CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE(Notes) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo ORDER BY Version DESC) newNotes 
  FROM tablename
)
UPDATE cte
SET Notes = newNotes
WHERE Version IS NULL AND Notes IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=586dd5822e931c2ffae9f76565b23bc1).

Answer (score 2):

Create a CTE to determine the value we need to update to, and then join that to your original table with update join syntax:

```
with maxVal as
(
    select row_number() over (partition by [Item No.] order by Version desc) rn
        , notes
        , [Item No.]
    from TestTable
    where Version is not null
)
update TestTable
set Notes = maxVal.Notes
from TestTable
left join maxVal
    on TestTable.[Item No.] = maxVal.[Item No.]
    and maxVal.rn = 1
where TestTable.Version is null
    and TestTable.Notes = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
-- Preparing a table variable
DECLARE @table1 AS TABLE (
    id  INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VersionID INT,
    ItemNo INT,
    Note Varchar(50)
)

insert into 
    @table1 (VersionID,ItemNo,Note)
values 
    (NULL,31,''),
    (1,31,'tasty'),
    (2,31,'kinda tasty'),
    (NULL,32,''),
    (1,32,'meh'),
    (2,32,'alright'),
    (3,32,'fabulous'),
    (NULL,33,'ambivalent'),
    (1,33,'gross'),
    (2,33,'puke');

-- update section 
update up set up.Note = db.Note
from @table1 up
inner join 
(
    select a.ItemNo,a.Note
    from @table1 a
    inner join 
    (
        select itemNo,Max(VersionID) as vs
        from @table1
        where Note <> ''
        group by itemNo
    ) as b on a.ItemNo = b.ItemNo and a.VersionID = b.vs
) as db on db.ItemNo = up.ItemNo and up.Note = ''


-- result
select * from @table1
```